# I have a LG xcharge that is stuck on the firmware update screen and my phone doesnt have a removable battery. what do i do?

Tags: lg

My phone is stuck on the firmware update screen and my phone doesn't have a removable battery. What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

Hold power button for 10+ seconds (for hard restart) or wait till the battery runs out.